# Is that possible and safe to add ENUM value to SQL database column type?

Tags: sql, mysql, enums

I have an application that works with database (PHP + MySQL).

One of the columns in the database table is of type `ENUM('VALUE1','VALUE2')`.

Is that possible to add safely `VALUE3` to the `ENUM` without damaging the data in the table ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you add to the end is seem safe , see the manual

> For some operations, a “fast” ALTER
>   TABLE is possible that does not
>   require a temporary table:
>       ....
>       Changing the definition of an ENUM or SET column by adding new
>   enumeration  or set members to the end
>   of the list of valid member values. 
>   (Adding members in the middle of the
>   list causes renumbering of existing
>   members, which requires a table copy.)

read in :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

also good point look in the article:

http://www.brandonsavage.net/why-you-should-replace-enum-with-something-else/

Comment: Thanks for the links. The second link is great!

Comment: Just a note that you should make sure there aren't any typos when writing the `ALTER TABLE` statement. If you miss one of the existing values, it will get thrown away.